# Can a URL from Firebase turn to enum Media? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, enums, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase database, I have a 'link' with some URL of a video as a value.

I'm trying to call it it via:

```
 enum Media {

    static let videoURL = "linkLabel.text = posts[selectedIndexPath].link"
}
```

Without success. If I call it just as a label text, it is fine. However, I also try the following:

```
        static let videoURL = URL(string: "linkLabel.text = posts[selectedIndexPath].link")
```

As well as trying to call from my `super.viewDidload()` like:

```
        videoVRView.load(from: URL(string: "\(linkLabel.text = posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"))
```

Anybody would know how to achieve this correctly? It will be amazing! Thanks!

----- EDIT:

I got it work by `videoVRView.load(from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"))`

Comment: I do not understand exactly what your question is. Could you try to explain in more detail exactly your problem and what you hope to achieve? Thanks

Comment: Hi Mike,

I m trying in that video URL = to give the value stored in my firebase database . . . I've updated another code I'm trying, without any sucess as well :( :(

Comment: is `posts[selectedIndexPath].link` a String value?